# How to scan or decode QRCode and EAN_13 barcode using blackberry API 6?

Tags: blackberry, qr-code

How to scan or decode QRCode and EAN_13 barcode using blackberry API 6? Any help is appreciated. I have searched lot on google but haven't find any proper solution.

My Code is.....

```
formats.addElement(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
formats.addElement(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
```

But i can't decode EAN_13 barcode but only QRCode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to decode EAN_13 barcode then you have to rotate scanded image in CW or give the image which is already rotated.